# Getting breakpoints to work with jest, Visual studio code and a custom typescript transformer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I can't get breakpoints to work in VSCode using [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) as a custom preprocessor.
If i use a `debugger` statement, it will break at the correct place, and show the correct sources, so the sourcemaps are being loaded and parsed.

On every breakpoint VSCode reports:
`Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)`

This is my setup (the same setup works fine in webstorm both with `debugger` statements and breakpoints)

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Jest",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": [
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "sourceMaps": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

.tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json>jest

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx)$",
  "mapCoverage": true,
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "json"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": "inline"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi yeah, see my answer. It seems to work out of the box with later versions of ts-jest and node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in later versions of ts-jest, though I'm not quite sure why. Breakpoints should work with node 8 out of the box with the above setup.

For further details see : https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/212